# How right align navbar but not all the way to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have managed to right align the navbar items, but what I really want is to align it to 3/4 of the way across the page.

[Here](https://www.rstudio.com/workshops/building-tidy-tools/) is a close example of the end result I'm trying to achieve (note that the navbar isn't exactly 3/4 the way across, but it's close enough in that it's not over on the very far right)

Currently, my code is

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-default bg-default fixed-top"> 

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>FAQ</li>
  <li>Info</li>
  <li>About</li>
  </ul> 

</nav>
```

Where `navbar-right` is what I added to  successfully move the nav bar from the left to the (very) far right.

How can I get the navbar items to align to the right, but only 3/4 the way across the page, rather than all the way?

Note: I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: did you try adding class "pull-right"?

Comment: @LasseEdsvik I tried just now, it seems to have an extremely similar (although not identical) effect to `navbar-right`, in that it right aligns the navbar items, but all the way to the (extreme) right

Comment: if pull-right doesnt work, its because some element got "width: 100%" or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `ul` with a `div` having class `.container`. This class gives margins from left and right and make content visible in between the viewport.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-default bg-default fixed-top"> 
   <div class="container">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>FAQ</li>
      <li>Info</li>
      <li>About</li>
     </ul> 
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: This is very helpful. It works, but creates another (minor) problem in that the far left and far right of the navbar are both white (whereas the navbar was previously all grey). In other words it looks like the navbar itself has been compressed, rather than having the navbar cover the entire width of the screen. The items on the navbar are now exactly where I want them though

Comment: @user5783745 I have updated the code in answer. Please check if it works?